# Imacros DS CMD=CLICK not working correctly

Tags: imacros

I'm having some trouble with DS CMD=CLICK. It's only working part of the time.

Here is the series of tasks I'm trying to accomplish. There is a list of addresses on the bottom third of a webpage and a map on the top two-thirds . Each address is numbered. When the address is clicked, the map centers in on the address. The bottom third with the list of addresses remains unchanged.

When the map centers in on the address, I need the DS CMD=CLICK to click on the center of the screen. Once it's clicked, a popup comes up and that's where lines 11 on come into play.

For some reason, DS CMD=CLICK only seems to work occasionally.

I know for a fact that all of the addresses I'm trying are valid and have a pop up when clicked because I did it manually to make sure everything would work correctly.

Here is my code:

```
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://URL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:{{!LOOP}}
SIZE X=1231 Y=835
WAIT SECONDS=5.171
DS CMD=CLICK X=613 Y=335 CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=ID:mapBalloonCommands
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>To<SP>List
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:balloonCloseBtn
WAIT SECONDS=3
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Also, I'm using the imacros browser if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: DS doesn't work any more. The newer versions don't support it.

Comment: Hmm I'm wasn't aware of that. Are there any alternatives to DS? I tried googling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: There is no alternative. Try X Y recording and use http://wiki.imacros.net/SIZE